# atomic_or not atomically performing operation

Tags: multithreading, opencl, gpu, atomic

I have a kernel which uses a global uint array, and I want to access and change entries in that array from all threads using the `atom_or` function in OpenCL. 
The code:

```
void SetMove(int c, uint m, volatile __global uint *prevmove)
{
    uint idx = c >> 4;
    uint mask = m << (2 * (c & 15));
    atom_or(&prevmove[idx], mask);
}
```

I am implementing a BFS algorithm using OpenCL. This is done in 'waves', where in every wave, an array `in` of states is analyzed. Each GPU thread evaluates a single state, finds it's successors, and places them in a different array `out`. At the end of the wave the contents of `out` are places in `in`.

The `prevmove` array is to keep track of what action you should do in a certain state to find the goal state. The `SetMove` function updates `prevmove` when a thread finds a new state.

Now the problem is: 
The results are always non-deterministic. If I would chance the `atom_or` operation with a normal, non atomic `|=` operator, the kernel behaves exactly the same. I have tested this by checking how many entries in `prevmove` are nonzero when the algorithm terminates. This varies everytime I run my program.

Is cause of my problem due to not implementing the `atom_or` correctly or is it something else?

(I have `#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics : enable` in my kernel).

Comment: what is c variable?

Comment: Each thread finds multiple successor states from a certain state `p`. `c` here is one of those states, and `m` encodes what action is needed to get to `c` from `p`

Comment: Is c contiguous or totally random between threads?

Comment: Should be random between threads, although I think it's possible that threads might call this function with the same `c`

Comment: what happens when you use atomic_or ? because it should be preferred for 32 bit iintegers

Comment: I have tried that, and the behaviour is exactly the same.

Comment: atom_or does compile though, and the results are the same as using atomic_or. I'll try and get a reproducable example ready